# Giuga numbers, when reduced modulo 288, form something resembling an arithmetic progression?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, arithmetic-progressions

Recently Jonathan Sondow and Kieren MacMillan discovered that primary pseudoperfect numbers, when reduced modulo 288, form the arithmetic progression 6, 42, 78, 114, 150, 186, 222.  They speculated that the ninth PPN, as yet undiscovered , will equal 258 , when reduced modulo 288.

This remarkable discovery prompted me to look at  Giuga Numbers , reduced modulo 288, to see if a similar  arithmetic progression  exists in that case.
Only thirteen Giuga Numbers are known  and they form the following sequence (which is not an arithmetic progression, but if you ignore the fact that some numbers are repeated several times, then it is an arithmetic progression !).  The 13 known Giuga numbers , when reduced  modulo 288, give us the following sequence:   30 , 282 , 282 , 246 ,  210 , 210 ,  174 , 174 , 174 , 138 , 138 , 138 , 66  .

A  curious point is that  the number of times a  particular integer  appears in this sequence (or progression )  seems to be related to  the number of prime factors  that a Giuga number  possesses . For example , there is one Giuga Number with  3  prime  factors , thus 30 appears only once in this arithmetic progression ; there are two  Giuga Numbers  with  4  prime  factors (namely 858  and 1722 ) and thus  282 appears twice in this arithmetic progression;  there is one Giuga Number with 5  prime  factors (namely  66198 ) and thus 246  appears only once in this arithmetic progression;  there are  two Giuga Numbers  with  6  prime  factors , and thus 210  appears twice in this arithmetic progression ; Similarly, there are three  Giuga Numbers with  7  prime  factors , accounting for the three appearances of  174  in the pattern , and there are  three  Giuga Numbers with 8  prime  factors , accounting for the three appearances  of 138 in the pattern. The largest  known Giuga Number (found by Frederick Schneider in 2006) which has 10 prime factors, when reduced  modulo 288 , gives us a  66  in the arithmetic progression.
Notice that 102 is missing  in this sequence , presumably corresponding to the fact that no Giuga numbers  with nine prime factors are known. 
 Thus, there seems to be a relation between frequency of appearance in the sequence and the number of prime factors that a Giuga number possesses. Does anyone know why this should be the case ? Why should Giuga numbers, when reduced mod 288 , form this strange sequence, where frequency of appearance in the sequence seems to be related to the number of prime factors ?

Comment: quadratic residues may be a help ?

Comment: Is it only the **frequency** that is determined by the number of prime factors?  It seems simpler to just conjecture that the residue is determined by the number of prime factors.  This could be regarded as being related to your earlier question about Giuga numbers having exactly one prime factor of the form $4k+1$.